# How to create a string variable in Excel VBA to loop through based on variable name?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to set the variable names in a way that allows looping the code without having to type out an instance of each 'directory'.

The intent of this code is to count how many files are in each directory.

Code I have so far (doesn't work):

```
Sub CountFiles()

Dim xFolder() As Long
Dim xPath() As Long
Dim xCount() As Long
Dim xFile() As String    
Dim z As Long

xFolder(1) = "\\generic path"
xFolder(2) = "\\generic path2"

For z = 1 To 2    
    xPath(z) = xFolder(z) & "\*.xlsx"
    xFile(z) = Dir(xPath(z))
    Do While xFile(z) <> ""
        xCount(z) = xCount(z) + 1
        xFile(z) = Dir()
    Loop

    With Worksheets("test")
        .Cells(3, 2).value = xCount(z)
    End With
Next z

End Sub
```

If I don't use the looping method, I can just set the variables to be `xFolder1`, `xFolder2`, `xFolder3` etc., but then I'd have to run an instance of the code which loops through the directories to count for each iteration.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The code looks like it would work if you dimensioned your arrays `Dim xFolder(1 to 2)` and same for the rest.

Comment: You'd also want to make sure you are advancing the output cell `.Cells(2 + z, 2).Value = xCount(z)`

Comment: I tried that just now and it's giving me a "type mismatch" error. Would it be Dim xFolder(1 To 2) As Long still?

Comment: Most of your declared variables are arrays. Although longs or ints are used for accessing values within arrays, the type of the data stored in the array is what the array needs to be declared as. For instance, if you're storing strings in `xFolder`, then it needs to be declared as `Dim xFolder() as String`

Comment: No, you are populating `xFolder` with strings (`"\\generic path"`) so you'd need to declare it as the type that you're populating it with `Dim xFolder(1 to 2) As String`

Comment: So xFolder, xFile, and xPath should all be Strings.

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Made the changes and the code works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define all the following as `String` array, in your case you want each array to have 2 elements.

```
Dim xFolder(1 To 2) As String
Dim xPath(1 To 2) As String
Dim xCount(1 To 2) As Long
Dim xFile(1 To 2) As String
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and explanations surrounding types/arrays. Added the y variable to advance the output columns by 1 each time.

Final working code:

```
Sub CountFiles()

Dim xFolder(1 To 2) As String
Dim xPath(1 To 2) As String 
Dim xCount(1 To 2) As Long
Dim xFile(1 To 2) As String    
Dim z As Long
Dim y As Long

xFolder(1) = "\\generic path"
xFolder(2) = "\\generic path2"

For z = 1 To 2    
    xPath(z) = xFolder(z) & "\*.xlsx"
    xFile(z) = Dir(xPath(z))
    Do While xFile(z) <> ""
        xCount(z) = xCount(z) + 1
        xFile(z) = Dir()
    Loop

y = z + 1

    With Worksheets("test")
        .Cells(3, y).value = xCount(z)
    End With

y = 0

Next z

End Sub
```